# Mockito verify throws UnfinishedVerificationException

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4

In a test, I am using a mockobject:

```
@Mock
ListMultipleChoice<String> listMultipleChoiceMock;
```

I try to verify the use of its methods:

```
verify(listMultipleChoiceMock).setRequired(true);
verify(listMultipleChoiceMock).setMaxRows(2);
verify(listMultipleChoiceMock).setDefaultModel(any(IModel.class));
```

But it throws the following exception:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
>   Missing method call for verify(mock) here:

The exception points at this line:

```
verify(listMultipleChoiceMock).setMaxRows(2);
```

setMaxRows accepts an int.

When I comment this line out, the test succeeds. When I debug my program, I can see the method setMaxRows being set:

```
brandsListMultipleChoice.setMaxRows(brandLabels.size());
```

brandLabels is a List and size() returns an int.

I check the size of brandLabels and it is 2. I have tried anyInt() and 0 as well, both result in an exception being thrown.

What am I doing wrong? Why is this verification not succeeding?

Here is an example of my code, which will fail:

```
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.ListMultipleChoice;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyObject;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.whenNew;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Example.class})
public class ExampleTest {

    @Mock
    ListMultipleChoice<String> brandsListMultipleChoiceMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        whenNew(ListMultipleChoice.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(brandsListMultipleChoiceMock);

        Example example = new Example();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        verify(brandsListMultipleChoiceMock).setRequired(true);
        verify(brandsListMultipleChoiceMock).setMaxRows(1);
        verify(brandsListMultipleChoiceMock).setDefaultModel(anyObject());

    }
}
```

And the class being tested:

```
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.ListMultipleChoice;
import org.apache.wicket.model.IModel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.PropertyModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Example {

    private ListMultipleChoice<String> brandsListMultipleChoice;

    public Example() {

        List<String> brandLabels = new ArrayList<>();
        brandLabels.add("DEMO");

        brandsListMultipleChoice = new ListMultipleChoice<>("brands", new PropertyModel<Set<String>>(this, "brandProperty"), brandLabels);
        brandsListMultipleChoice.setRequired(true);
        brandsListMultipleChoice.setMaxRows(brandLabels.size());
        brandsListMultipleChoice.setDefaultModel(new IModel<Set<String>>() {
            private Set<String> list = new HashSet<>();

            @Override
            public Set<String> getObject() {
                return list;
            }

            @Override
            public void setObject(Set<String> ts) {
                list = ts;
            }

            @Override
            public void detach() {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I comment out either the second or the third verify rule, the test succeeds.

Comment: what is the type of brandLabels.size() ? What is the type accepted by setMaxRows ?

Comment: I have added the information to my question. setMaxRows accepts int, brandLabels.size() returns int.

Comment: Are you sure that brandsListMultipleChoice is your mock ?

Comment: Yes. I've verified through debugging. Otherwise the setRequired and setDefaultModel would have to fail as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is not possible to mock final methods.

The sollution to this problem is adding the mocked class to the annotation @PrepareForTest(ListMultipleChoice.class)

In this way PowerMockito will handle the mocked object.

Answer (score 0):

I try write simple test:

```
public class ListMultipleChoiceTest {
    public class ListMultipleChoice<T>{
        public void setMaxRows(int maxRows) {
        }
    }

    @Mock
    ListMultipleChoice<String> listMultipleChoiceMock;

    @Test
    public void testSetMaxRows() {
        verify(listMultipleChoiceMock, never()).setMaxRows(2);
        listMultipleChoiceMock.setMaxRows(2);
        verify(listMultipleChoiceMock).setMaxRows(2);
    }
}
```

And it pass successfully.
You should check carefully of your class usage.
Or give more code sample.

Comment: I have edited my post with code that will fail the test.